# How to solve mysql database-unity connection problem using mysql connector and c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, unity-game-engine, mysql-connector

I have created a server with Unity 2019, collecting some data and I struggle to connect to my MySQL database. The database is stored locally.
I can access my DB in a simple C# project (not Unity) but have no luck with Unity.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue ?

---

So far I found some post about importing dll from the MySQL connector.net :

- https://sigitov.de/how-to-add-mysql-capabilities-to-a-unity-application/
- https://www.codedojo.com/?p=2132
- [How do I import MySql Connector into Unity Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050951/how-do-i-import-mysql-connector-into-unity-project)

I added the following dll :

- From MySQL Connector.Net 8.0 (in MySQL\ConnectorNET8.0\Assemblies\v4.5.2 folder)

  - MySQL.Data.dll
  - BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
  - Renci.SshNet.dll
  - SshNet.Security.Cryptography.dll
  - Google.Protobuf.dll
- From Unity Mono2.0 :

  - I18N.CJK.dll
  - I18N.dll
  - I18N.MidEast.dll
  - I18N.Other.dll
  - I18N.Rare.dll
  - I18N.West.dll

Using this I was able to use  `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` and create a `MySqlConnection`.

However when I try to open the connection I get :

```
Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

I verified the string used to create the MySqlConnection by using the same string in another C# project and it works fine there.

I tried adding charset ([Unity3D connection to MySQL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057309/unity3d-connection-to-mysql-error)), putting capital letters ... but no improvement.

At this point I don't know if Unity is blocking in some way the connection or if I'm missing something.

It seems that I am not the only one struggling with this ([Accessing MySQL database using c# on unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029389/accessing-mysql-database-using-c-sharp-on-unity), https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/902wy3/best_way_to_retrieve_game_data_item_list_stats/, https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/c7b101/is_it_possible_to_use_systemdatasqlclient_in/, https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/8c25mu/unity_server_how_to_connect_to_mysql/).

I am aware that some people use PHP (or some other webserver) as a "middleman" between Unity and MySQL but it sounds a bit overkill for something working just fine in C# outside Unity...

Here is the code I use for the connection to MySQL, `connection` is a `MySqlConnection`, private member of my class, I tried those lines in the classic Unity `Start` function of my class

```
string dataSource = "localhost";
string port = "3306";

if (connection != null)
{
    connection.Close();
}

string connStr = "Datasource=" + dataSource +
                 ";port=" + port +
                 ";username=" + Global.Username +
                 ";password=" + Global.Password +
                 ";database=" + dbName;

connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

try
{
    Debug.Log("Connecting to MySQL...");
    connection.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Just to let you know : I also posted the question on reddit (r/Unity3D)

Comment: *"I have created a server with Unity 2019, collecting some data and I struggle to connect to my MySQL database"*.. Your application is a server, which clients never have acces to decompile/disassemble then yes then using PHP as MySQL gateway is pretty much redundant

Comment: We need to see some code so we know what you are doing

Comment: .. also try to search stackoverflow [Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+connect+to+any+of+the+specified+MySQL+hosts.) as it is a common error..

Comment: I have added the code I used to connect to the database so you can see.

Comment: I tried the same code outside Unity and it worked so I think the code is correct.
I will do more search for the Unable to connect error. However in most of posts I have seen about it the error is caused by a wrong connection string (which I assume is not the case as the same string is working in my simple C# app).

Comment: *"I tried the same code outside Unity and it worked so I think the code is correct"* You have to be aware that Unity uses transpilers to convert C# code into [IL2CPP (Intermediate Language To C++)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html) to make cross platform compilation builds possible..

Comment: I didn't know that. But the call to the connector dynamic library must remain the same even if the code is transposed in another language I suppose? I don't see why it could cause a problem, do you have an idea to bypass that if the problem come from the IL2CPP?

Comment: What Unity install/modules do you have in Unity 2019 and for what platform are you building?   By the way?

Comment: .. oh after review -> *" When building a project using IL2CPP"* So IL2CPP also seams totally optional.. *"But the call to the connector dynamic library must remain the same even if the code is transposed in another language I suppose? "* I would guess so but the dynamic library linking might still be platform build depening

Comment: I verified, IL2CPP is not selected as scripting backend in the project setting.
I build for Windows 10.
The only asset I use is JsonDotNet from Newtonsoft, and I edit the question to add the dll that I added for MySQL and their origin.

Comment: Which Unity 2019 version?   I assume you have Universal Windows platform build support as module install as you build for Windows 10..  Also Which MySQL server version are you using -> `SELECT VERSION()` as Connector/NET Version 8 is meant to be able to connect to MySQL 5,6 5,7 8.0 ...